# How to convert a buffer array into an image

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, buffer

In the database I have images of type buffer, how can I convert my buffer data into an image and display image on the frontend.

The backend is made in node.js sequelize MYSQL.

and the frontend in react.js

[it is response date from server. Image its an object of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYmwq.png)
get request on the server

```
router.get("/", validateToken, async(req,res) => {
  const UserId = req.user.id;
  console.log(UserId)
  const listOfCollect = await Collections.findAll({
    where: {
      UserId: UserId,
    }
  });
  res.json(listOfCollect);
});
```

frontend

```
useEffect(() => {   
  axios.get("http://localhost:3001/collect", {
    headers: {
      token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    }
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      setListOfCollect(response.data);
    });
 }, []);
```

display an object on the page

```
{listOfCollect.map((value,key) => {
   return (
     <Col key={key} className="collect-block">            
     <img src={value.image} alt="collectimage" 
        onClick={() => {
          history.push(`/post/${value.id}`);
        }}>
     </img>
     <div className="collect-block_title"> {value.name}</div>
     <div className="collect-block_description"></div>
     <button
       onClick={() => {
         deletePost(value.id);
       }}
     >
     {" "}
       Delete Post
     </button>
     </Col>
     )
   })}
```

[and in this way the image is stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjKWV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should try URL.createObjectURL(blob)

```
testImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Also, to `responseType: "blob"` to the request if using axios

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL